# Find an element in a jQuery object built from a string of HTML

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to be able to build a jQuery object from a string of HTML and to search inside directly.

Example:

```
htmlString = '<h3>Foo</h3><div class="groups"></div>'
$html      = $(htmlString)
$groups    = $html.find('.groups') // Returns []. WTF?
```

I would expect that `find` actually finds the `div` element.

If you want to know more about the context of my question, I develop a Backbone app and to render certain Views I have things like that:

```
render: ->
  $html   = $(@template(vehicle: @vehicle))
  $groups = $()

  _(@groups).each (group)=>
    subview = new App.Views.AttributesGroup(group: group, vehicle: @vehicle)
    $groups = $groups.add(subview.render().el)

  $(@el).html($html)
  $(@el).find('.groups').replaceWith($groups)
  @
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way to achieve the same result.

Thanks!

---

Thanks Matt, it is very clear. I feel stupid for not having thought of this subtlety about descendent and siblings.

So I refactored my code:

```
render: ->
  $html   = $(@template(vehicle: @vehicle))
  $groups = $html.filter('.groups')

  _(@groups).each (group)=>
    subview = new App.Views.AttributesGroup(group: group, vehicle: @vehicle)
    $groups.append(subview.render().el)

  $(@el).html($html)
  @
```

Now there is only one DOM insertion and the code looks clearer to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `find()` searches the descendants of the elements in the jQuery object, but the `.groups` element *is* an element in the jQuery object so won't be matched.

Instead, you need to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to search the current elements.

```
htmlString = '<h3>Foo</h3><div class="groups"></div>'
$html      = $(htmlString)
$groups    = $html.filter('.groups');
```

However if you then had the `htmlString` of `<h3><span class="bar">Foo</span></h3><div class="groups"></div>`, you wouldn't find `.bar`; this would be a `find()` call.

So you'll need to check for both;

```
htmlString = '<h3>Foo</h3><div class="groups"></div>'
$html      = $(htmlString)
$groups    = $html.find('.groups').add($html.filter('.groups'));
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, it is very clear. I feel stupid for not having thought of this subtlety about descendent and siblings. Here is how I refactored the code: https://gist.github.com/2585965.